# How can I get zsh to display international characters properly?

Tags: macos, bash, zsh, utf-8, international

I just started using zsh, and love it. However, I've stumbled upon an annoyance when it comes to international characters:

```
➜  ~  touch åäö.txt               
➜  ~  ls                          
Desktop       Dropbox       Music         Sites
Documents     Library       Pictures      a??a??o??.txt
Downloads     Movies        Public
➜  ~  rm -v a<030a>a<0308>o<0308>.txt
åäö.txt
➜  ~
```

With bash it looks like this (the filename in `rm -v` is auto completed by pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> in both cases).

```
johan@retina ~ $ touch åäö.txt
johan@retina ~ $ ls
Desktop       Dropbox       Music         Sites
Documents     Library       Pictures      åäö.txt
Downloads     Movies        Public
johan@retina ~ $ rm -v åäö.txt 
åäö.txt
johan@retina ~ $
```

How can I fix this with `zsh`?

EDIT:

Setting `export LANG=en_US:UTF-8` fixes the output of e.g. `ls` and also shows it properly on the line below current input when there are multiple matches on <kbd>TAB</kbd>-completion. However, selecting the file from <kbd>TAB</kbd>-completion it shows the wrong way on the input line, the same goes for when there is only one match.

The above example now looks like this with `zsh`:

```
➜  ~  touch åäö.txt               
➜  ~  ls                          
åäö.txy
➜  ~  rm -v a<030a>a<0308>o<0308>.txt
åäö.txt
➜  ~
```

If I have two files matching on <kbd>TAB</kbd>-completion it looks like this:

```
➜  ~  touch åäö.txt               
➜  ~  touch öäå.txt                          
➜  ~  rm 
öäå.txt    åäö.txt
```

Selecting one of the above by pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> again and using arrow keys, or pressing either a or o to only make one match before completion generates this:

```
➜  ~  rm o<0308>a<0308>a<030a>.txt
➜  ~  rm a<030a>a<0308>o<0308>.txt
```

Any suggestions on what's wrong?

Comment: What's the output of `echo $LANG` in `bash` resp. `zsh`?

Comment: It's blank for both. I'm on OS X 10.8.3 by the way.

Comment: Ok, then I'm out (OS X), sorry. But try nevertheless e.g. `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`. `zsh` should offer you all possibilities with `LANG=<TAB>`, but en_US.UTF-8 works perfect with german umlauts.

Comment: `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` fixed the `ls` output, however, the auto completion still shows `a<030a>a<0308>o<0308>.txt`

Comment: Just another idea: Did you compile `zsh` yourself? If not, grab latest source (http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Arc/source.html) and be sure to use `./configure --enable-multibyte`. After `make` just try by starting `./Src/zsh` prior installing that version.

Comment: It's compiled/installed with homebrew. 5.0.2 with `--enable-multibyte`.

Answer (score 10):

Thanks @mpy for solving the LANG problem. The answer is to use:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

in your `.zshrc`.

The remaining problem is caused by the completion system. Unfortunately completion is a monster feature. It involves shell functions or perhaps even scripts being called and somewhere in that process possibly LANG is again set to a wrong value. If you have root privileges you can debug this shell script code). Good luck with the 
[completion guide](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide06.html).

Answer (score 2):

Try

1. Having a Powerline compatible font installed https://github.com/powerline/fonts
2. Setting these ENV vars in `.zshrc`:

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Comment: This fixed my locale issue both on Debian 10 and macOS Mojave. I didn't install any powerline fonts though. zsh were installed with apt and brew accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in Arch Linux using zsh.

Using bash everything works just fine, but when I switch to zsh some characters were displayed wrong (e.g. ñ,°).

I've added `export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"` to my `.zshrc` and nothing happened.

I did everything to set LANG inside zsh and nothing fixes.

Then I changed my shell back to `bash` with `chsh -s /bin/bash` and I noticed my env var LANG was wrong with `printenv LANG` it showed me `LANG=C`.

This is a new installation so I forget to create `/etc/locale.conf` file and set my  `LANG="en_US.UTF-8"` and after restarting everything work perfect.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is still the same on the last versions of `zsh` which come
with `Mac OS X` 10.8 (aka Mountain Lion), 10.9 (aka Mavericks) & 10.10 (aka Yosemite) (I am still beta testing 10.11 and can't disclose information about it).
The completion of `zsh` is failing.

The `port` version is working correctly at least with version 5.1.1:

```
/usr/bin/sudo port install zsh
```

Test:

```
/opt/local/bin/zsh
```

`% touch hølé`
`% ls -l htab`

`→ ls -l hølé`

`% -rw-r--r--  1 bob  wheel  0 Apr  2 18:49 hølé`

`%`